# I have a report that needs to be opened in another tab, but only if the validation doesn't fail

Tags: jsf

Still i didn't get proper answer  please provide proper answer what i can update for solution let me know. Sorry if this question has been answered. I already searched and still couldn't solve my problem.  I have a report that needs to be opened in another tab, but only if the validation doesn't fail. In my case, the validation fails and the same page opens in another tab with the validations erros.

Comment: My code snippet

<p:commandButton id="generate" value="Generate" ajax="false" 
           style="margin-left: 10px" 
           action="#{reportManagedBean.summaryReport}"
            update="@form" 
                                         oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) window.open('reportURL') " >
          </p:commandButton>

Comment: Please give me a solution for above issue i should need to open a new tab when it get validation success ,but not should not open new tab at fail case.

Comment: Current using snippet which is  opening  new tab for fail case also.advise me

<p:commandButton id="generate" value="Generate"
          style="margin-left: 10px" ajax="false"
          actionListener="#{reportManagedBean.summaryReport}"
          onclick="this.form.target='_blank'">
         </p:commandButton>

Comment: Hi BalusC  i need the answer in more explain way for my code snippet  if possible give me Thanks

Comment: Still i did'nt get answer for this , i used all the ways which mentioned in other answers  but it is not working